# When generating N sets of numbers, how do I make sure none are duplicates?

Tags: python

I'm completely new to python, but am working on a passion project. I'm currently trying to figure out how to ensure that no sets of numbers generated in the code below are duplicates of each other.

```
from random import choices
for count in range(100):
    attHair = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    attHair1 = choices(attHair, weights = [0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3, 0.25])

    attEyes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    attEyes1 = choices(attEyes, weights = [0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])

    attCone = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    attCone1 = choices(attEyes, weights = [0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])

    attColor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    attColor1 = choices(attEyes, weights = [0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])

    attAcces = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    attAcces1 = choices(attEyes, weights = [0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])

    attShadow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    attShadow1 = choices(attEyes, weights = [0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])

    Attributes = attHair1 + attEyes1 + attCone1 + attColor1 + attAcces1 + attShadow1
    print(Attributes)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What number shouldn't be a dupllicate ? Because in each loop round you select 6 numbers out of 6. Also if each list is the same (ie number from 1 to 6) you don't need to define 6 different lists

Comment: You're going to need to give us a little bit more context.  What is your function supposed to do?  What have you tried?  What about did you want and what did you expect?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't too clear on that end -- In this case, every set will generate 6 numbers, it doesn't matter if these are duplicates. What I'm trying to get to is for no two sets to be a duplicate.

Comment: So no duplicate on `Attributes` ?

Comment: Correct, I'm aiming for every single `Attributes` printed to be unique

Comment: And do you want 100 different attributs OR run 100 round of loop, and no matter if there is only 90 different values at the end ?

Comment: 100 different `Attributes` is what I'm looking for, even if the loop has to run over 100 times to achieve it. 

Also, sorry for not being too clear, and thanks for being patient -- this is my first time on StackOverflow, your patience is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `set` to filter the duplicate, as a `set` keeps only unique elements. use a `while` loop to continue until you reach `100` elements

Each `att*` is a list of 1 element, so when using `+` you're concatenating them you get a list and that isn't hashable (can't be in a set) you may convert them to `tuple`

```
attHair1 + attEyes1 + attCone1 + attColor1 + attAcces1 + attShadow1
# [6, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6]
tuple(attHair1 + attEyes1 + attCone1 + attColor1 + attAcces1 + attShadow1)
# (6, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6)
```

---

Final code

```
from random import choices

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
result = set()

while len(result) < 100:
    attHair1 = choices(values, weights=[0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3, 0.25])
    attEyes1 = choices(values, weights=[0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])
    attCone1 = choices(values, weights=[0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])
    attColor1 = choices(values, weights=[0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])
    attAcces1 = choices(values, weights=[0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])
    attShadow1 = choices(values, weights=[0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5, 0.25])

    result.add(tuple(attHair1 + attEyes1 + attCone1 + attColor1 + attAcces1 + attShadow1))
```

Giving

```
{(3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1), (1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2), ..., (4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5), (5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1)}
```

Comment: @Yorowne is that normal that the 1st weight is different ? And that their sum is not equal to 1  ?

Comment: Yeah, no worries about that -- this is just the test version, the actual will have a different # of `values` for each `att*`, I was just trying to figure out how to do it first. Thank you for the help!